# Normalise heart rate data

Tags: time-series, dataset, normalization

I need to statistically examine time series of heart rate data over many different users. Since I don't have data for each user for each instance, I should find a way to normalise the data so that I can somehow average them (different users have different baseline heart rate, variance, response rate and potentially other characteristics). Any ideas on how to do that? I could statistically normalise the heart rates, or take the z-values,... is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: each instance - is not clear. What is instance?

Comment: Well, listeners listen to multiple songs (= instance), while the heart rate is recorded. And I somehow want a good representation so that I can take the combined heart rate over listeners per song.

Comment: Why do you think you need to normalise? Most analyses use the different conditions as predictor variables so that different values can be modelled.

Comment: So do you want to impute your missing values? Or do you need just to have some average characteristic for each song, without imputation? What type of average do you want - average time series or just single number? Do you have a heart rate for listeners who are listening silence (baseline)?

Comment: Hi German: That would be average time series. I don't have any missing values. I just believe it might not be correct to average over different individuals for each song without some kind of normalisation. Maybe a simple standardisation (x-average)/var could work, but maybe there is something a bit more correct out there.

Comment: @nick: I was thinking about normalising because I have data for different users for each song (so it wasn't the same group of users whose heart rate was collected for each song, but a different group)

Comment: Indeed, but my point still applies. It's easier, in my experience, (A) to develop a model with predictors used as they come that compares different instances than (B) to explain what you "normalised" and what you didn't and then explain your model. With (B) you have all sorts of constants outside the model that you need to report too. That's not a strategy I see in modelling texts or courses.

Comment: In bioinformatics normalisation is typically done not by mean, but by total library size (so if you have large time series with, for example, 1000 of observations, you can divide your data by sum of all values, and in the end you will get smth that sums up to 1). But the approaches is similar. I guess you can just divide on mean, your values will sum up to number of points in a time series.

Comment: @german, oh so your mean take the average across all subjects at each time

Comment: @dorien no, each sample should be divided by mean of the sample. Or sum of values in the sample. You have vector of $x_i$ for each sample, you need to perform $\frac{x_i}{\sum_i x_i}$. It is not good if your data at each time point has skewed distribution, but if $\sum_i x_i$ is approx. equal for each sample, it is OK.